# How to get rid of empty row in vb.net while reading file

Tags: vb.net

Below is code to read data from .CSV file which has 3 columns (keeps varying). Sometimes when user opens the .csv in Excel and deletes a row in it, the row gets read as an empty or whitespace row with comma separation.

When same is read through code I get ",," as input which gets added to my dataTable as an empty row. How can I escape this blank row?

```vb
Dim sreader As StreamReader
Dim sstring As String
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim counter as Integer
sreader = File.OpenText(Path.ToString) 'this path is path of the excel
    
While sreader.Peek <> -1

    sstring = sreader.Readline()
    If sstring <> " " then  ' how can I check here that the string does not have any content in it except for the seperating commas
    Dim str As String () = sstring.Split(",")
    
    
    Dim rowdt As DataRow
    rowdt = dt.NewRow()
    
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.count-1
        rowdt(i) = str(i).ToString()
    Next

    dt.rows.Add(rowdt)
    End if
Counter = counter + 1
End While
```

I tried something. Have posted in Answer section

This is what I tried

```
Dim sreader As StreamReader
Dim counter as Integer
Dim sstring As String
Dim dt As DataTable
sreader = File.OpenText(Path.ToString) 

 While sreader.Peek <> -1

 sstring = sreader.Readline()

 Dim no as integer = 0

 For each str as String in sstring.Split(",")
  If str.ToString.Trim = "" then
   no = no + 1
   End If
  Next


  If no <> 3 then 
 Dim str As String () = sstring.Split(",")


 Dim rowdt As DataRow
 rowdt = dt.NewRow()

  For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.count-1
rowdt(i) = str(i).ToString()
Next

 dt.rows.Add(rowdt)
 End if
 End if
counter = counter + 1
End While
```

Comment: See if the sstring has a comma in it.  If it doesn't, don't process it.

Comment: @LarsTech It will by default have commas in it whether there is content or no. Since file is .csv. I need solution for same.

Comment: @LarsTech I have tried as you have suggested. Please check if that's what you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read all the lines, then process only lines where there is any value between commas

```vb
Dim path = "filename.txt"
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.AddRange(
    {
        New DataColumn("Column1"), New DataColumn("Column2"),
        New DataColumn("Column3"), New DataColumn("Column4"),
        New DataColumn("Column5"), New DataColumn("Column6"),
        New DataColumn("Column7"), New DataColumn("Column8"),
        New DataColumn("Column9"), New DataColumn("Column10")
    })

Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
sw.Start()

Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path)
For Each line In lines
    Dim split = line.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    If split.Any(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) Then
        Dim row = dt.NewRow()
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            row(i) = split(i).ToString()
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(row)
    End If
Next

sw.Stop()
Console.WriteLine($"Took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms")
Console.WriteLine($"Read {dt.Rows.Count()} rows")
```

Tested to address performance concerns

File contents 1024 lines of `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j` and some lines of `,,,,,,,,,` mixed in, including the final line of the file

*Final* 10 lines of the file:

> a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
>
> a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
>
> ,,,,,,,,,
>
> ,,,,,,,,,
>
> a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
>
> a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
>
> ,,,,,,,,,
>
> a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
>
> a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
>
> ,,,,,,,,,

A StopWatch object shows it takes 2ms to read all lines. And there are exactly 1024 lines of data in the resulting DataTable. The processor skips rows with no values

> Took 2 ms
>
> Read 1024 rows

Comment: The user will delete rows he doesn't require from the file before uploading. Not the columns

Comment: I cannot afford to include more loops to the code as it will disturb the performance. Is there any built in function available in VB to get this checked.

Comment: @MurielMi I just tested this with a csv file of 1024 lines each with 10 columns, and it took 2ms. Let me know if that needs modification for additional performance analysis

Comment: @MurielMi Slow code in VB.NET can be caused by not using [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement). Not using it can make the code 10x slower as it has to do conversions that should have been done in the program before it was compiled.

Comment: @MurielMi to add to the `Option Strict On` comment, and maybe this led to it, you are certainly not using it, as evidenced by this `sstring.Split(",")` (that overload takes a char, not a string) but still, even with this implicit conversion this code will take 2ms

Comment: @MurielMi `Is there any built in function available in VB to get this checked.` no that's why we write code

Comment: @djv can u please explain what line number 3 and 4 of your code.

Comment: @MurielMi `Dim split = line.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.None)`: we take a line of your file and split it by comma. The result is an array of string with each item between the commas. Then `If split.Any(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) Then`: If any of those strings is not null or empty. If you have an empty line, it will just be ",,,,,,,,," and that split is 10 empty strings. That is what you get when an empty row is added at the end of Excel, saved as csv. So we ignore those rows

Comment: @djv thanks. I also tried something out. What's your opinion on it?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried splitting and checking the string. Hope it works.

```vb
Dim sreader As StreamReader
Dim counter as Integer
Dim sstring As String
Dim dt As DataTable
sreader = File.OpenText(Path.ToString) 

While sreader.Peek <> -1

    sstring = sreader.Readline()

    Dim no as integer = 0

    For each str as String in sstring.Split(",")
        If str.ToString.Trim = "" then
            no = no + 1
        End If
    Next

    If no <> 3 then 
        Dim str As String () = sstring.Split(",")

        Dim rowdt As DataRow
        rowdt = dt.NewRow()

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.count-1
            rowdt(i) = str(i).ToString()
        Next

        dt.rows.Add(rowdt)
    End if
    End if
    counter = counter + 1
End While
```

Comment: The `no` and `For each str...` loop can be replaced with `Dim no = sstring.split(","c).Count(Function(s) s.Trim() = "")`. Then you split again in the next block, so just split once above and reuse the variable.

Comment: Otherwise it's similar to my answer. Except you need to dispose the StreamReader. A `Using sreader As New StreamReader(Path.ToString()) ... End Using` block would help you there.

Comment: And I'll add, this is the same complexity as my answer except you still leave the reader open and read within the loop, which keeps the file open longer. So it's an inferior method for reasons I've already mentioned. The performance is worse, and the difference is probably negligible, but you brought it up.